# Getting error in when using ValidateForgeryTokenAttribute.salt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to use below line above Action method

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Salt = Constants.AntiForgeryTokenSalt)]
```

And i am getting error on build time

```
ValidateForgeryTokenAttribute.salt is obsolete: the salt property is deprecated. To specify custom data to be embedded within the token, use the static AntiforgeryConfig.AdditionalDataProvider property

'constant' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

My mvc version is 5.2.3. I've already added namespace system.web.mvc in controller

Your answer will appreciable:)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.
You have a build warning and a build error

**Warning**

As you can tell you should not use the salt property in the warning and follow it's suggestion.

**Error**

The build error is because you cannot access the `Constants` class due to it's protection level. You will need to make the class `public` to be able to access it (Or `internal` if you are in the same assembly).

Comment: We're accessing this thing from system.web.mvc. so how we can set public class inside assembly?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's referencing `Constants` in `System.Web.MVC`?